# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'`

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

Declared a bitmap which was

```
private Bitmap img1 = null;  
private Bitmap img2 = null;
```

the image will be putted after selecting it from **openFileDialog**.
the selected images were placed in an array.

```
imgName = openFD.FileNames;
```

then button1 to display these image.

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgName[0]);  
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(imgName[1]);
```

i replaced the button1 code with this

```
img1 = Image.FromFile(imgName[0]);  
img2 = Image.FromFile(imgName[1]);
```

but an error occurs

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'

I'd try to change the code to `img1 = Bitmap.FromFile(imgName[0]);`. but still has the same error.
Any suggestion how to correct or do this right?

Comment: While a Bitmap is always considered an Image, an Image is not necessarily a Bitmap.  It provides future support for other types of images.  Therefore, you should not try to force an Image to be a Bitmap.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
img1 = new Bitmap(imgName[0]);
img2 = new Bitmap(imgName[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
img1 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(imgName[0]);
img2 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(imgName[1]);
```

As the error message says you cannot implicitly do this you need to explicitly cast it to `Bitmap`

**Edit**

Based on the comments below I would suggest either go with icktoofay's answer i.e. use the Bitmap constructor or if you can use the Image class directly instead of using Bitmap you can also go with that

Comment: You can't just cast things to whatever you want. This is programming, not magic. `Bitmap` inherits from `Image`, but not the other way around. That means you can't implicitly convert an `Image` object to a `Bitmap` object. Casting just tells the compiler to shut up, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: So what would be the right way here. Use the Bitmap Constructor or use Image class directly? I guess right way would be to use Image unless you are sure that uploaded file is a Bitmap. What do you think?

Comment: Hard to say. If you need a `Bitmap`, then you'll need to create an instance of the `Bitmap` class, probably using the constructor. Otherwise, declare the variable that you're assigning to (`img1` and `img2`) as objects of the `Image` class and your problems go away. The point is that casts are rarely the correct answer. The compiler is trying to warn you of a potential problem: you should heed its suggestions.

Comment: Image.FromFile() *usually* returns a Bitmap so the cast will work.  Not always, it can also return a Metafile.  Kaboom then.  The sane thing to do is to use the Bitmap(string) constructor.

Comment: sorry for this, i am just new to c# programming. 
i used icktofay's answer and it worked. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I have used these three lines in my code to assing byte value to image in c#.

```
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
pbStudentPicture.Image =  (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(StudentPinfo.Picture);
pbStudentPicture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, my `System.Drawing.Image` wasn't coming from a file but rather from a device's camera. Since I didn't want to save the image to a file as an intermediary step, I used the following approach:

```
var imageBitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imageBitmap))
    graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
```

Maybe this is helpful to others ;)

Comment: You can do this in a simpler way; simply with `var imageBitmap = new Bitmap(image);`. Same result.